# Main Activity overlay with fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a problem where when I call my fragment by pushing a button in main activity, its overlay with the main activity. It make both of them on top of each other. I would want the fragment to cover a part of the main activity so the item behind are not viewable. I already user replace() when I want to start the fragment but it still did not work. I can still see the main activity behind of the fragment like picture below:

I want to avoid using visible for the main activity because in my main project there is a lot of item (CalenderView, RecyclerView, etc) behind it.

[image]

Here is my main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button mShowPaymentButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mShowPaymentButton = findViewById(R.id.show_payment_button);

    /*FrameLayout blurContainer = findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
    Blurry.with(this)
            .radius(25)
            .sampling(2)
            .onto(blurContainer);*/

    mShowPaymentButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("10.00");
        PaymentFragment paymentFragment = PaymentFragment.newInstance(amount);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_top, R.anim.slide_out_to_top);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, paymentFragment, paymentFragment.getTag());
        //fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    });
}}
```

MainActivity xml:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show_payment_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment code:

```
public class PaymentFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_AMOUNT = "amount";
    private Button mPayButton;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    EditText mCardNumberEditText;
    EditText mExpiryDateEditText;
    EditText mCvvEditText;
    ImageButton closeButton;
    EditText mErrorTextView;
    private BigDecimal amount;

    public PaymentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static PaymentFragment newInstance(BigDecimal amount) {
        PaymentFragment fragment = new PaymentFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_AMOUNT, amount);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payment, container, false);
        mPayButton = view.findViewById(R.id.pay_button);
        //mProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        mCardNumberEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.card_number_edit_text);
        mExpiryDateEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.expiry_date_edit_text);
        mCvvEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.cvv_edit_text);
        //mErrorTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.error_text_view);
        mPayButton = view.findViewById(R.id.pay_button);
        closeButton = view.findViewById(R.id.close_button_payment);

        amount = (BigDecimal) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_AMOUNT);
        mPayButton.setText("Pay RM "+amount);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fragmentTransaction.remove(PaymentFragment.this).commit();
            }
        });

        mPayButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // Show the progress bar
            //mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPayButton.setEnabled(false);

            String cardNumber = mCardNumberEditText.getText().toString();
            String expiryDate = mExpiryDateEditText.getText().toString();
            String cvv = mCvvEditText.getText().toString();

            if (cardNumber.isEmpty() || expiryDate.isEmpty() || cvv.isEmpty()) {
                //mErrorTextView.setText("Please enter all required fields.");
                //mErrorTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
               /* mProgressBar.postDelayed(() -> {
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mPayButton.setEnabled(true);
                    fragmentTransaction.remove(PaymentFragment.this);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }, 2000);*/
                fragmentTransaction.remove(this).commit();
            }
        });

        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -view.getHeight(), 0);
        animation.setDuration(500);
        view.startAnimation(animation);

        return view;
    }
}
```

fragment xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#590E0E0E"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/close_button_payment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#AAAAAA"
        android:src="@drawable/close_payment_button" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Add your payment information"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_number_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Card number:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/card_number_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/expiry_date_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Expiry date:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/expiry_date_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cvv_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CVV:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cvv_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pay_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pay" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/error_text_view"
        android:layout_width="378dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any advice and suggestion would really help. Thanks in advance. There is no error from my code but maybe can be optimize.

Comment: Does it work if you don't use the TranslateAnimation ?

Comment: It still do not work. @gioravered

Comment: Can you share your animations xml?

Answer (score 0):

- Change your `activity_main.xml` like:

```xml
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```